# port install command freezes when installing subversion via MacPorts

Tags: xcode, svn, osx-mountain-lion, macports, configure

I'm having a problem installing subversion via MacPorts.  The command output from `port` is:

```
# port install subversion
--->  Computing dependencies for subversion
--->  Configuring subversion
```

At this point, it sits there indefinitely.  I Ctrl+C'd out of that, and ran port with the -d option to get some debug information, this is what I get:

[Pastebin containing command output](http://pastebin.com/SGs8kf9J)

So at this point, I can see it's getting stuck in the `configure` script either at the end of the python checks, or the beginning of the next check.

The `configure` script in this case is located at `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_subversion/subversion/work/subversion-1.7.7`

`configure` calls a helper script (`$abs_srcdir/build/find_python.sh`) which returns `python`, the `configure` script then does some checks, and returns the full path to the `python` executable, and moves onto the next check.  The next check, as per line 20129 of `configure`, is for a JVM (which I do have installed).  Without manually iterating through the configure script further, I thought I check here and see if there's any advice to be had from the community.

```
Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)
MacPorts v2.1.2
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Xcode 4.5.2 (with up to date command line tools)
Python 2.7.2
```

If there's any other information that's relevant that I neglected to include, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install subversion by hacking the configure script to just set the OSX_VERSION to hardcoded "10.8" and running the port install command again. For some reason it is hanging on the series of commands:

`/usr/bin/sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | cut -f2 | cut -d"." -f1,2`

I think the second cut is the problem because running ps -ef in a second window show the cut `-d"." -f1,2` still running. Maybe try to surround the `-f1,2` with quotes?

However, simply setting `OSX_VERSION="10.8"` in ALL locations in the configure script allowed me to install subversion!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds stupid, I know... but did you try to restart your system?

After upgrading OS X (and therefore also Xcode), I also got stuck in configure with different packages (ccutils, gmp, and others). Spent some time looking for an answer, reinstalled everything, nothing helped.

Restarting was the last resort... and did the trick for me :/